# Styling the Active Step of the Wizard control

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to change the style of the current/active step of the ASP.NET Wizard control but nothing works so far. The code below applies the style to all the existing steps. I'm not sure how to apply the formatting on the current step. Any ideas?

```
 <SideBarButtonStyle cssclass="SideBarButtonStyle"  Font-Names="Verdana" 
   ForeColor="336699" Width="100px"  />
```

CSS

```
.SideBarButtonStyle { 
     background-color: #F7F7F7;
     Color: #336699; font-size: 0.9em; 
}
```

Comment: There is no rule named `font-name` in CSS, it's `font-family`

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak ok thanks but that doesn't change anything. I edited the code.